# Boost errors occure in utility headers after upgrading from 1.55.0 to 1.72.0

Tags: c++, boost

I am currently upgrading `boost` from 1.55.0 to 1.72.0 where boost was built with MSVC 141, even though the utility headers have not changed much since 1.55.0, there are quite a few errors that I cannot find a workaround for.

When compiling the solution I recieve hundreds of errors similar to the following:

```
boost-1_72_0\boost\utility\detail\result_of_iterate.hpp(43): error C2977: 'boost::result_of': too many template arguments
```

and:

```
boost-1_72_0\boost\utility\detail\result_of_iterate.hpp(27): error C2065: 'BOOST_RESULT_OF_ARGSA': undeclared identifier
```

And so on...

Nothing else is specifed besides the project in the error list. When I try and inspect the boost header files, Visual Studio (2017) IntelliSense indicates that something is wrong with boost. Example of an error being shown in result_of_iterate.hpp:

```
template<typename R,  typename FArgs BOOST_PP_ENUM_TRAILING_PARAMS(BOOST_PP_ITERATION(),typename T)>
struct tr1_result_of_impl<R (&)(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(BOOST_PP_ITERATION(),T)), FArgs, false>
{
  typedef R type;
};
```

Here tr1_result_of_impl yields a a template argument list is not allowed in a declaration of a primary template error. Is there a chance that boost has been built incorrectly or could it be something completely different?

If more context is needed please let me know.

Comment: Please show how you are including the boost headers (minimum compilable example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was a macro F in a different dependency which clashed together with typename F in boost. Replacing the macro with a different name and changing all instances(easily done with grepWin) removed all errors.